# I'm having trouble configuring Cypress for component testing on my Vite app

Tags: unit-testing, configuration, automated-tests, cypress, vite

I'm trying to configure Cypress for component testing on a Vite app that I recently completed. Unfortunately, Cypress is looking for the vite.config.js in the root folder of the app instead of the client folder where the vite.config.js is stored. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

I've tried moving the config file to the root folder, which allows me to configure Cypress for component testing but this messes with the build process when I run the app.

Comment: Hey, Dan. Can you share what's the folder's structure, plus a bit of the config files? Is your Cypress app installed in your client's folder?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be all you need, but see example `cypress.config.js` here [vite-dev-server](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/develop/npm/vite-dev-server/README.md) that explicitly loads the vite.config from a specified location.

Try setting your particular path in the `require()` parameter.

```js
import { devServer } from '@cypress/vite-dev-server'
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer(devServerConfig) {
      return devServer({
        ...devServerConfig,
        framework: 'react',
        viteConfig: require('./vite.config.js')
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I'm also seeing it resolve the config passed above here: [createViteDevServerConfig](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/8638abb2d0082809c8eea559f7ba4af74fd61c4a/npm/vite-dev-server/src/resolveConfig.ts#L32)

```js
  const { 
    viteConfig: inlineViteConfig,     // this is the config file require()'d above
    cypressConfig: { projectRoot } 
  } = config
  let resolvedOverrides: InlineConfig = {}

  if (inlineViteConfig) {
    debug(`Received a custom viteConfig`, inlineViteConfig)

    if (typeof inlineViteConfig === 'function') {
      resolvedOverrides = await inlineViteConfig()
    } else if (typeof inlineViteConfig === 'object') {
      resolvedOverrides = inlineViteConfig                  // ... used here
    }

    // Set "configFile: false" to disable auto resolution of <project-root>/vite.config.js
    resolvedOverrides = { configFile: false, ...resolvedOverrides }
  } else {
...
```